# se produjo una excepcion en el destino de la invocacion c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo el siguiente código con `Entity Framework` al momento de realizar el guardado hago una pequeña validación en base a un criterio de que si la fecha contiene una fecha valida.

```
public void Guardar_Actualizacion_Datos(int tempLim, TextBox txtCodigo, TextBox txtCedula, TextBox txtTarjeta,
        TextBox txtArea, TextBox txtPich, MaskedTextBox masFeIng, MaskedTextBox masFeAf,MaskedTextBox masFeUltAfi, MaskedTextBox masFecSal,
        MaskedTextBox masFecNac, ComboBox cmbEstado,ComboBox cmbSexo ,TextBox txtMotivo, ComboBox cmbTrabajador, TextBox txtAcuDec, MaskedTextBox masCtaCte)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Entities_Sisrol db = new Entities_Sisrol())
            {
                if (masFeAf.Text == "00/00/0000" || masFeAf.Text == "30/12/1989")
                {
                    db.TBL_EMPLEADO.Where(d => d.EMPL_COD.Equals(txtCodigo)).Update(x => new TBL_EMPLEADO()
                    {

                        EMPL_COD = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text),
                        EMPL_CEDU = txtCedula.Text,
                        EMPL_NOTA = txtTarjeta.Text,
                        EMPL_AREA = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArea.Text),
                        EMPL_CTA_PIC = txtPich.Text,
                        EMPL_FECH_AF = 0,
                        EMPL_FECH_UAF = (int)(DateTime.Parse(masFeUltAfi.Text).Date).ToOADate(),
                        EMPL_FECH_SA = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecSal.Text),
                        EMPL_STATUS = cmbEstado.Text,
                        EMPL_CTA_CTE = masCtaCte.Text,
                        EMPL_SEXO = cmbSexo.Text,
                        EMPL_MOTIVO = txtMotivo.Text,
                        EMPL_FEC_NAC = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecNac.Text),
                    });
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro Actualizado", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    tempLim = 1;
                    Limpiar(tempLim, txtCodigo, txtCedula, txtTarjeta, txtArea, txtPich, masFeIng, masFeAf, masFeUltAfi, masFecSal, masFecNac, cmbEstado,cmbSexo, txtMotivo, cmbTrabajador, txtAcuDec, masCtaCte);
                }
                else if (masFeAf.Text != "00/00/0000" || masFeAf.Text == "30/12/1989")
                {
                    db.TBL_EMPLEADO.Where(d => d.EMPL_COD.Equals(txtCodigo)).Update(x => new TBL_EMPLEADO()
                    {

                        EMPL_COD = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text),
                        EMPL_CEDU = txtCedula.Text,
                        EMPL_NOTA = txtTarjeta.Text,
                        EMPL_AREA = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArea.Text),
                        EMPL_CTA_PIC = txtPich.Text,
                        EMPL_FECH_AF = (int)(DateTime.Parse(masFeAf.Text).Date).ToOADate(),
                        EMPL_FECH_UAF = (int)(DateTime.Parse(masFeAf.Text).Date).ToOADate(),
                        EMPL_FECH_SA = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecSal.Text),
                        EMPL_STATUS = cmbEstado.Text,
                        EMPL_CTA_CTE = masCtaCte.Text,
                        EMPL_SEXO = cmbSexo.Text,
                        EMPL_MOTIVO = txtMotivo.Text,
                        EMPL_FEC_NAC = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecNac.Text),
                    });
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro Actualizado", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    tempLim = 1;
                    Limpiar(tempLim, txtCodigo, txtCedula, txtTarjeta, txtArea, txtPich, masFeIng, masFeAf, masFeUltAfi, masFecSal, masFecNac, cmbEstado,cmbSexo, txtMotivo, cmbTrabajador, txtAcuDec, masCtaCte);
                }
                else if (masFeAf.Text != "00/00/0000" || masFeAf.Text != "30/12/1989")
                {
                    db.TBL_EMPLEADO.Where(d => d.EMPL_COD.Equals(txtCodigo)).Update(x => new TBL_EMPLEADO()
                    {

                        EMPL_COD = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text),
                        EMPL_CEDU = txtCedula.Text,
                        EMPL_NOTA = txtTarjeta.Text,
                        EMPL_AREA = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArea.Text),
                        EMPL_CTA_PIC = txtPich.Text,
                        EMPL_FECH_AF = (int)(DateTime.Parse(masFeAf.Text).Date).ToOADate(),
                        EMPL_FECH_UAF = (int)(DateTime.Parse(masFeUltAfi.Text).Date).ToOADate(),
                        EMPL_FECH_SA = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecSal.Text),
                        EMPL_STATUS = cmbEstado.Text,
                        EMPL_CTA_CTE = masCtaCte.Text,
                        EMPL_SEXO = cmbSexo.Text,
                        EMPL_MOTIVO = txtMotivo.Text,
                        EMPL_FEC_NAC = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecNac.Text),
                    });
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro Actualizado", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    tempLim = 1;
                    Limpiar(tempLim, txtCodigo, txtCedula, txtTarjeta, txtArea, txtPich, masFeIng, masFeAf, masFeUltAfi, masFecSal, masFecNac, cmbEstado,cmbSexo, txtMotivo, cmbTrabajador, txtAcuDec, masCtaCte);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: ACT. DATOS " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Al momento de guardar me arroja el error del titulo y en la ventana salida me arrojan estos valores.

```
Excepción producida: 'System.NotSupportedException' en EntityFramework.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.NotSupportedException' en EntityFramework.dll
```

Adicional el `StackTrace` me arroja lo sgte.

```
en System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   en .(ObjectQuery , Boolean )
   en Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.BatchUpdate.CreateCommand[T](ObjectQuery query, SchemaEntityType`1 entity, List`1 values, Boolean hasZZZQueryHook)
   en Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.BatchUpdate.Execute[T](IQueryable`1 query, Expression`1 updateFactory)
   en DbContextExtensions.[](IQueryable`1 , Expression`1 , Action`1 , Boolean )
   en DbContextExtensions.UpdateFromQuery[TEntity](IQueryable`1 query, Expression`1 updateExpression, Action`1 bulkOperationFactory)
   en Sisrol_Net.dao.Data_Metodos_Otros.Guardar_Actualizacion_Datos(Int32 tempLim, TextBox txtCodigo, TextBox txtCedula, TextBox txtTarjeta, TextBox txtArea, TextBox txtPich, MaskedTextBox masFeIng, MaskedTextBox masFeAf, MaskedTextBox masFeUltAfi, MaskedTextBox masFecSal, MaskedTextBox masFecNac, ComboBox cmbEstado, ComboBox cmbSexo, TextBox txtMotivo, ComboBox cmbTrabajador, TextBox txtAcuDec, MaskedTextBox masCtaCte) en D:\Proyectos\Sisrol-Net\Sisrol-Net\dao\Data_Metodos_Otros.cs: línea 265
```

Que podría estar realizando erróneamente o si me pueden guiar hacia el posible error, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Por lo menos a mi ese error no dice nada que pueda ayudar a entender lo que pasa. y francamente tu código tiene demasiada grasa que deberías quitar

Comment: @Yussef en este caso al momento de hacer la actualización de los datos directamente cae en error y no hay una guia si es por efecto de alguna variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de varios meses , al fin encontré la solución realice la actualización directamente con LINQ y no con Zplus y funciono sin problema.

```
   public void Save_frm_Actualizacion_Datos(int tempLim,int CodObr, TextBox txtCodigo, TextBox txtCedula, TextBox txtTarjeta,
     TextBox txtArea, TextBox txtPich, MaskedTextBox masFeIng, MaskedTextBox masFeAf,MaskedTextBox masFeUltAfi, MaskedTextBox masFecSal,
     MaskedTextBox masFecNac, ComboBox cmbEstado,ComboBox cmbSexo ,TextBox txtMotivo, ComboBox cmbTrabajador, TextBox txtAcuDec, MaskedTextBox masCtaCte)
 {
     try
     {
         using (Entities_Sisrol db = new Entities_Sisrol())
         {
             if (masFeAf.Text == "00/00/0000" || masFeAf.Text == "30/12/1989")
             {
                 var empleado = db.TBL_EMPLEADO.Where(x => x.EMPL_COD.Equals(CodObr)).FirstOrDefault();
                 {

                     empleado.EMPL_COD = CodObr;
                     empleado.EMPL_CEDU = txtCedula.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_NOTA = txtTarjeta.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_AREA = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArea.Text);
                     empleado.EMPL_CTA_PIC = txtPich.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_FECH_AF = 0;
                     empleado.EMPL_FECH_UAF = (int)(DateTime.Parse(masFeUltAfi.Text).Date).ToOADate();
                     empleado.EMPL_FECH_SA = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecSal.Text);
                     empleado.EMPL_STATUS = cmbEstado.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_CTA_CTE = masCtaCte.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_SEXO = cmbSexo.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_MOTIVO = txtMotivo.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_FEC_NAC = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecNac.Text);
                     db.SaveChanges();
                 }
                 MessageBox.Show("Registro Actualizado", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                 tempLim = 1;
                 Limpiar(tempLim, txtCodigo, txtCedula, txtTarjeta, txtArea, txtPich, masFeIng, masFeAf, masFeUltAfi, masFecSal, masFecNac, cmbEstado, cmbSexo, txtMotivo, cmbTrabajador, txtAcuDec, masCtaCte);
             }
             else
             if (masFeAf.Text != "00/00/0000" || masFeAf.Text == "30/12/1989")
             {
                 var empleado = db.TBL_EMPLEADO.Where(x => x.EMPL_COD.Equals(CodObr)).FirstOrDefault();
                 {

                     empleado.EMPL_COD = CodObr;
                     empleado.EMPL_CEDU = txtCedula.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_NOTA = txtTarjeta.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_AREA = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArea.Text);
                     empleado.EMPL_CTA_PIC = txtPich.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_FECH_AF = (int)(DateTime.Parse(masFeAf.Text).Date).ToOADate();
                     empleado.EMPL_FECH_UAF = (int)(DateTime.Parse(masFeAf.Text).Date).ToOADate();
                     empleado.EMPL_FECH_SA = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecSal.Text);
                     empleado.EMPL_STATUS = cmbEstado.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_CTA_CTE = masCtaCte.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_SEXO = cmbSexo.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_MOTIVO = txtMotivo.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_FEC_NAC = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecNac.Text);
                     db.SaveChanges();
                 }
                 MessageBox.Show("Registro Actualizado", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                 tempLim = 1;
                 Limpiar(tempLim, txtCodigo, txtCedula, txtTarjeta, txtArea, txtPich, masFeIng, masFeAf, masFeUltAfi, masFecSal, masFecNac, cmbEstado, cmbSexo, txtMotivo, cmbTrabajador, txtAcuDec, masCtaCte);
             }
             else if (masFeAf.Text != "00/00/0000" || masFeAf.Text != "30/12/1989")
             {
                 var empleado = db.TBL_EMPLEADO.Where(x => x.EMPL_COD.Equals(CodObr)).FirstOrDefault();
                 {

                     empleado.EMPL_COD = CodObr;
                     empleado.EMPL_CEDU = txtCedula.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_NOTA = txtTarjeta.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_AREA = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArea.Text);
                     empleado.EMPL_CTA_PIC = txtPich.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_FECH_AF = (int)(DateTime.Parse(masFeAf.Text).Date).ToOADate();
                     empleado.EMPL_FECH_UAF = (int)(DateTime.Parse(masFeUltAfi.Text).Date).ToOADate();
                     empleado.EMPL_FECH_SA = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecSal.Text);
                     empleado.EMPL_STATUS = cmbEstado.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_CTA_CTE = masCtaCte.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_SEXO = cmbSexo.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_MOTIVO = txtMotivo.Text;
                     empleado.EMPL_FEC_NAC = Convert.ToDateTime(masFecNac.Text);
                     db.SaveChanges();
                 }
                 MessageBox.Show("Registro Actualizado", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                 tempLim = 1;
                 Limpiar(tempLim, txtCodigo, txtCedula, txtTarjeta, txtArea, txtPich, masFeIng, masFeAf, masFeUltAfi, masFecSal, masFecNac, cmbEstado, cmbSexo, txtMotivo, cmbTrabajador, txtAcuDec, masCtaCte);
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: ACT. DATOS " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     }
 }
```